# Can't connect Samsung phone to PC

Tags: samsung, usb, usb-connection-mode

My SM-J701F (Android 7.0) stopped connecting to any PC after a failed root attempt using KingRoot(PC). I have been using the official Samsung cable, and the phone used to connect just fine before i tried Kingroot. Now the phone just charges itself after being connected via USB. 
I've tried setting USB config as MTP, installing MTP drivers in PC, uninstalling phone drivers from my PC, changing cables, changing PCs themselves- nothing works. Neither the PC nor the phone detects any connection. 
The phone can't be rooted now, so I can't find a way to restore it to a previous backup either.

Please help.

Comment: Please tell me how I can use Odin and flash custom recoveries without USB connectivities.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ODIN, reflash that phone and be ready to go from official firm again. Simple. Or if you want a complicated way of getting that done you can say so that imma show you

Comment: Yeah. Explain that complicated way please

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the system is the hard way. Did the phone gain root access finally or it halted upon Kingroot's trial? So that I may know what exactly to say to you? If it didn't, you should try another application to try rooting it, install a custom recovery highly recommending TWRP and then backup another device of the same type and restore it on your phone of incase you don't want to loose your personal data. Ensure you backup only data folder of your phone without the system partition and restore it after doing the backup from other phone. Kingoroot is another tough rooting alternative